# ¿Cómo hacer el texto responsive fijándolo a la imagen de fondo?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy utilizando una imagen de fondo ubicada en el CSS en la cual posiciono arriba de la misma dos líneas de texto y un botón. Mi intención era que se adaptara tanto el texto y la imagen a un diseño responsive teniendo el texto e imagen siempre anclados.

Me encuentro con el problema de que al querer testear si cumplían estos elementos con el diseño responsive los dos a la vez resulta que la imagen se separa del texto y no quedan anclados como tenía pensado.

Quisiera que el texto, botón e imagen estén siempre en esa posición y sean responsive sin que se separen del image background.

Quedo atento a sus respuestas para encontrar mi error.

**Testear el código en pantalla completa achicando acortando las dimensiones para comprender mejor mi error e inconveniente**

```css
.main .row2 {
  background: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/514f6f4ce4b023ca29000709/1619545371720-NGX1L9ENSQ4DNUH2XRVY/street-scrambler-family-timeline-urban-scrambler-handling-1920x780.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  /* margin-top: -1%; */
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
  min-height: 80vh;
  /* margin-bottom: -5%; */
  border-bottom: #EEE7CE 1px solid;
}

.main .row2 .content h3 {
  padding-top: 7%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(251, 255, 0);
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: xx-large;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.main .row2 .content h2 {
  margin-top: -1%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(196, 218, 0);
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.main .row2 .content p {
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: #1e1e1f;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin-right: 25%;

}

.main .btn4 {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0.4%;
  left: 32.5%;
  top: 1890%;
  width: 19%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #FFC728;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3%;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  border: 1.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}

.main .btn4 i {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.main .btn4:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.main .btn4:hover:before {
  bottom: 0%;
  top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.main .btn4:before {
  border-radius: .6rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  color: #000000;
  background: #FFC728;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}

/* BARRA LATERAL COLOCADO PARA EJEMPLIFICAR */
/* NO PRESTARLE IMPORTANCIA */

.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #1d2f33;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #1d2f33;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleImageTextResponsive.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="header-2">
      </div>
    </nav>
    <article class="main">
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="content">
          <h3>TESTEANDO TEXTO RESPONSIVE</h3>
          <h2>Imagen de fondo</h>
          <a href="#" id="login-btn" class="btn4"><i class="uil uil-images"></i>BUSCAR IMAGEN</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, al achicar la pantalla, la imagen genera un espacio arriba y abajo, esto es debido a que lo estás posicionando siempre al centro cuando queremos achicar la imagen:

```
background-position: center center;
```

Entonces, comentamos esta línea y así tu imagen se posicionará arriba, sin generar espacios en ambos lados. Ahora el siguiente problema sería que tus textos se desbordan de tu imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observamos que tu contenedor es hasta esa línea color naranja, y tu imagen solo ocupa el **ancho** al 100% de la pantalla, haciendo que su **altura** se adapte a ese ancho (es por eso que tiene ese espacio blanco debajo), entonces hagamos que tu imagen ocupe siempre toda la altura de tu contenedor, quitando la siguiente propiedad:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Y reduzcamos un poco los textos para que no se vean muy gigantes en pantallas chicas, utilizando la regla [**`@media`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) de CSS (esto lo puedes personalizar a tu gusto):

```
@media (max-width: 765px) {
  .main .row2 .content h3,
  .main .row2 .content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  .main .btn4 {
    font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  }
}
```

Y obtienes un mejor resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo:

```css
.main .row2 {
  background: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/514f6f4ce4b023ca29000709/1619545371720-NGX1L9ENSQ4DNUH2XRVY/street-scrambler-family-timeline-urban-scrambler-handling-1920x780.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-position: center center; */
  /* margin-top: -1%; */
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  /* background-size: 100%; */
  /* margin-bottom: -5%; */
  border-bottom: #EEE7CE 3px solid;
}

.main .row2 .content h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(251, 255, 0);
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: xx-large;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main .row2 .content h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(196, 218, 0);
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 90px;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 765px) {
  .main .row2 .content h3,
  .main .row2 .content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  .main .btn4 {
    font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  }
}

.main .row2 .content p {
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: #1e1e1f;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin-right: 25%;

}

.main .btn4 {
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 32.5%;
  top: 1890%;
  width: max-content;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #FFC728;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3%;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  border: 1.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}

.main .btn4 i {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.main .btn4:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.main .btn4:hover:before {
  bottom: 0%;
  top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.main .btn4:before {
  border-radius: .6rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  color: #000000;
  background: #FFC728;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}

/* BARRA LATERAL COLOCADO PARA EJEMPLIFICAR */
/* NO PRESTARLE IMPORTANCIA */

.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #1d2f33;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #1d2f33;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleImageTextResponsive.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="header-2">
      </div>
    </nav>
    <article class="main">
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="content">
          <h3>TESTEANDO TEXTO RESPONSIVE</h3>
          <h2>Imagen de fondo</h>
          <a href="#" id="login-btn" class="btn4"><i class="uil uil-images"></i>BUSCAR IMAGEN</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muy buena la explicación. Saludos compañero y gracias por tú tiempo!